# To store mysql row result as table format in php variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

here is my code

```
<?php 
while($rowcall=mysql_fetch_array($qry_call))
{
?>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $rowcall['caller_id'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $rowcall['did']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $rowcall['start_time']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $rowcall['end_time']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $rowcall['call_duration']; ?></td>
  </tr>
 </table> 
 <?php } ?>
```

I need to store this table in php variable $result.

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: do concatenation using **.** operator

Comment: Interesting that no `Stop Using mysql_*` comments here yet, but really you should :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

  $result = '';
  while($rowcall=mysql_fetch_array($qry_call))
  {
     $result .= '<table>';
     $result .= '<tr>';
     $result .= '<td>'.$rowcall['caller_id'].'</td>';
     $result .= '<td>'.$rowcall['did'].'</td>';
     $result .= '<td>'.$rowcall['start_time'].'</td>';
     $result .= '<td>'.$rowcall['end_time'].'</td>';
     $result .= '<td>'.$rowcall['call_duration'].'</td>';
     $result .= '</tr>';
     $result .= '</table>';
  }

  echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: With this code you would generate a seperate table for every element you get from the database

Comment: Yep, I know. But that's what @user2732605 want if I see his question

Comment: @BjornSmeets thats what the OP has asked, right? "To store mysql row result as table format in php variable"

Comment: You are right, my bad. I misunderstood the question and thought he wanted 1 big table with all the data as rows inside that table

Comment: Exactly @rakeshjain .

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
<?php 
    $result = "";
    while($rowcall=mysql_fetch_array($qry_call))
    {
        $result .= "<table>";
        $result .= "<tr>";
        $result .= "<td>".$rowcall['caller_id']."</td>";
        $result .= "<td>".$rowcall['did']."</td>";
        $result .= "<td>".$rowcall['start_time']."</td>";
        $result .= "<td>".$rowcall['end_time']."</td>";
        $result .= "<td>".$rowcall['call_duration']."</td>";
        $result .= "</tr>";
        $result .= "</table>";
    } 

    echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty basic PHP;

```
<?php 
$result="";
while($rowcall=mysql_fetch_array($qry_call))
{
    $result.="  <table>";
    $result.="  <tr>";
    $result.="  <td>".$rowcall['caller_id']."</td>";
    $result.="  <td>".$rowcall['did']."</td>";
    $result.="  <td>".$rowcall['start_time']."</td>";
    $result.="  <td>".$rowcall['end_time']."</td>";
    $result.="  <td>".$rowcall['call_duration']."</td>";
    $result.="  </tr>";
    $result.=" </table>"; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    *<?php

  $result = '';
  while($rowcall=mysql_fetch_array($qry_call))
  {
     $result .= '<table>';
     $result .= '<tr>';
     $result .= '<td>'.$rowcall['caller_id'].'</td>';
     $result .= '<td>'.$rowcall['did'].'</td>';
     $result .= '<td>'.$rowcall['start_time'].'</td>';
     $result .= '<td>'.$rowcall['end_time'].'</td>';
     $result .= '<td>'.$rowcall['call_duration'].'</td>';
     $result .= '</tr>';
     $result .= '</table>';
  }

  echo $result;

?>*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try on these lines. Also switch to mysqli_* rather than mysql_* as the one you are using is deprecated

```
<?php 
$str="";
while($rowcall=mysql_fetch_array($qry_call))
{
  $str .= "<table>
  <tr>
  <td>{$rowcall['caller_id']}</td>
  <td>{$rowcall['did']}</td>
  <td>{$rowcall['start_time']}</td>
  <td>{$rowcall['end_time']}</td>
  <td>{$rowcall['call_duration']}</td>
  </tr>
 </table>"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: @BjornSmeets thats what the OP has asked, right? "To store mysql row result as table format in php variable"

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to see docs at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

start and end the `<table></table>` tag out side while loop no inside it will create a new table for every row but that's you don't want